# Previously-working rsync operation failling in recent Windows 8.1 update showing "error in socket io"

Tags: ubuntu, freebsd, rsync, backuppc, windows-8.1

I have been running rsync and rsyncd on my Windows boxes for years and only recently have I had an issue.

Apparently, when my Linux and FreeBSD boxes try to sync their data with what's on the Windows machines, the Windows-side shows this in the log:

```
2013/11/30 05:21:50 [2164] connect from example.com (192.168.1.100)
2013/11/30 05:21:52 [2164] rsync error: error in socket IO (code 10) at /home/lapo/package/rsync-3.0.9-1/src/rsync-3.0.9/io.c(1486)
```

And the Linux and FreeBSD sides show this in the command line:

```
user@example.com$ rsync windows-machine::data
Password:
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [Receiver]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(605) [Receiver=3.0.9]
```

Normally this would list out the available files, now it's giving me this error. 3 of my machines are showing this, all on Windows 8.1. None of them have backed for a while; except one which backed up two days ago (Nov 28th) but hasn't been able to since.

I am assuming something changed in the security settings of a recent Windows 8.1 update which is causing these errors.

I tried a few things, updating to rsync 3.0.9 from 3.0.8 and seeing if the ports were open etc. From what I'm seeing, port 873 is open. When connecting, the log is updated and an rsync.lock file is created. Removing the file does not change anything. It does list the available modules, and I did verify the machine had access to those files.

The port is open, a connection is being made, and it is failing during the connection

Is there any explanation for why this is happening and a possible workaround or solution to fix it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can fix this by updating the cygwin1.dll file.